# views.py files not recognised as Python files in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, debugging, pycharm, ide

**I am encountering problems while coding Django using Pycharm...**

As you could see from the picture, for unknown reasons my Python file were recognised as text files... Even if there are coloring, the auto-fill for my code is definitely different from writting in other Python files.

Here is the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Pretty much appreciate it!

Comment: Is it colouring just for modified files (blue)?

Comment: Yep that was blue because it was modified... But the icons are different... Python files should be using a different icon? This is quite weird...

Comment: Yes, it is weird, On the other hand, it seems it recognize some syntax highlighting. Could you check the beginning of the file? Is there something that could tell PyCharm that the file is something other (e.g. in comments), or do you have some special plug-in installed?

Comment: I have checked everything from my end I think and after checking I restored all my settings to default and that worked for me, lol. Don't know where does this bug come from but just get it sorted out. Thx man. It had been confusing me for months! 

Comment: Was not a symlink? The "anchor" is strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resetting config is too radical. `views.py` was associated with a wrong file type (text?) in **Settings | Editor | File Types**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, mine was listed in **Settings | Editor | File Types | Auto-detect file type by content**. Once I removed it from there, pycharm was once again working like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

**1. Method:**
Refresh Pycharm or Quit and open Pycharm again (restart Pycharm)
**2. Method:**
Wait for a minute, if there are a loading bar in bottom of Pycharm window
**3. Method:**
Reinstall Pycharm if both are not working
Happy coding!

Comment: Restoring pycharm settings worked for me. Same as reinstalling. Appreciated!